# Inner product term in Augmented Lagrangian

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, numerical-optimization

I am confused about the inner product term in the ALM.

For example, 
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\min_{\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{z}} \quad f_{1}(\boldsymbol{x})+f_{2}(\boldsymbol{z})\\
&\text { s.t. } \quad A x+B z=b
\end{aligned}
$$

is equivalent to $$
\operatorname{max}_{\lambda} \min_{x, z} f_{1}(x)+f_{2}(z)+ \langle A x+B z-b, \lambda\rangle+\frac{\rho}{2}\left\|A x+B z-b \right\|_{2}^{2},
$$

where $\lambda$ is the Lagrangian multiplier and $\rho$ is the penalty term.

I have read some papers which 'simplify' the above formula into 
$$
\operatorname{max}_{\lambda} \min_{x, z} f_{1}(x)+f_{2}(z)+ \frac{\rho}{2}\left\|A x+B z-b + \frac{1}{\rho} \lambda\right\|_{2}^{2}.
$$

I am very confused why the inner product term can be merged into the quadratic term since this implies the $\frac{1}{\rho} \| \lambda\|_2^2$ is pushed to zero.

Can anyone tell me the equivalence of two formula? What is the initution behind it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: since $\frac{1}{\rho} \| \lambda \|_2^2$ is independent of $x$ and $z$, then it doesn't matter in the optimization. In other words, when you take the derivative with respect to $x$ and $z$, then $\frac{1}{\rho} \| \lambda \|_2^2$ is zero, if you like to say.

Comment: @user550103 I see. Thanks for your answer.